# Margins between divs not showing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a series of pages which contain information in columns, but I can't seem to get a visible border between the columns. The HTML and CSS in basic format are as follows:

```html
<div class="row central">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <img class="img-responsive sub_img" src="images/zz_image.jpg" alt="Image">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2>heading</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p>Text.</p>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">

        <img class="img-responsive sub_img" src="images/zz_image2.jpg" alt="Image">
                </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h2>heading2</h2></div></div>
            <p>Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.central{
    background-color: white;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

The background color for body is `#808080`, which results in a horizontal line between the rows. What I would also like is a vertical line between the two columns, which should switch to a horizontal line between them when the screen reduces in size and the second column drops below the first, but nothing I do can get that.

I've tried applying `.central` style to the columns, but they no longer display side by side, so that isn't it.

Comment: So you need border to all your columns which contains information about cities?

Comment: Yes, that's right - proving tricky!

Comment: Leo - thanks it's now working fine with the borders below, plus using a JS plugin to keep the columns the same height.  Now struggling with other issues!

Comment: well good but if you have other issue then please share with us and will love to help..:)

Comment: Thanks for the offer.  I am attempting to meet the challenge!  My site works fine in Chrome, IE, Firefox on PC.  My hamburger icon doesn't appear in Safari when the media query is invoked below 640px, and then the "hover" CSS menu doesn't function on a touch screen device!  I'm attempting to adapt a solution from Osvaldas Valutis.  If I come unstuck, I'll let you know!

Comment: all the best and ok if there is anything i can help then let me know..and position properties is the reason, your css menu is not working in monile view..

Answer (score 0):

Give another class name to the (the main one) and give it borders with the color you require.

```
<div class="row central">
<div class="col-md-6 setborder">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="img-responsive sub_img" src="images/zz_image.jpg" alt="Image">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>heading</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>Text.</p>
</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 setborder">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">

    <img class="img-responsive sub_img" src="images/zz_image2.jpg" alt="Image">
            </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>heading2</h2></div></div>
        <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

```
<style>
 .setborder{
 border:solid;
 border-color:#808080;
  </style>
```

Comment: Great - that worked, thanks.  I hadn't put "Solid" in the CSS file, only the px.  I have also had to use a bit of Javascript I got from GitHub, Sam152, which makes columns with different sized contents in a row the same height.  Now it's looking good, and I'm now close to finishing this project